# Password input Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to log in my forum using Selenium. I can write my username without problems, but I can't say the same with my password. This is my code:

```
driver.get("https://testocolo.forumcommunity.net")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("UserName")
username.send_keys("*****************")
time.sleep(1)
passwd = driver.find_element_by_name("PassSafe")
passwd.send_keys("*****************")
```

The html code of the password box is divided in two parts, with differents names and styles (*display: none* and *display: inline*):

```
<input type="password" size="8" maxlength="32" name="PassWord" value="" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.style.display='none';this.form.PassSafe.style.display='inline'}" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" size="8" maxlenght="32" name="PassSafe" value="Password" onfocus="this.style.display='none';this.form.PassWord.style.display='inline';this.form.PassWord.focus()" style="display: inline;">
```

If i try to find the first element by name (PassWord) is not interactable. I can interact with the second element (I can also see the cursor blinking in the password box during the execution of the script) but then when I'm going to send my password it doesn't show up and I get the same error, "element not interactable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solutions right after posting it.
Simply:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("PassSafe").click()
passwd = driver.find_element_by_name("PassWord")
passwd.send_keys("*****************")
passwd.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I clicked in the second element, and doing so the first element became style="display: inline;", so I can send the key and clicking enter i'm logged in.